# Facebook Share doesn't work when i send my url with get parameter

Tags: php, facebook, get

I want to share this url on Facebook:

```
http://exapmle.com/?id=120
```

I tried this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titleheresexily&p[url]=http://exapmle.com/?id=120&p[summary]=mysexysummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://exapmle.com
```

This doesn't work because in my url I have 1 get parameter: `?id=120`

I tried this, too:

```
<?php
$title=urlencode('Title of Your iFrame Tab');
$url=urlencode('http://exapmle.com/?id=120');
$summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your tab is about, or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');
$image=urlencode('http://www.yourdomain.com/images/share-thumbnail.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: You could pass the url without the get parameter if you made use of `mod_rewrite` on your `.htaccess` file

Comment: URL-encoding the value _is_ the correct thing to do here. (What you possibly did _wrong_ with that, we can’t tell you, if you don’t show us exact code.) And the sharer.php does not take additional parameters besides the URL any more – all other information will be taken from the Open graph meta tags of the URL shared. If you want to specify these values at runtime, you can use the Feed dialog instead.